# Compare two git branches

Tags: git, github

I have `master` and `develop` branches. `develop` shows it's 20 commits ahead and 1429 commits behind `master`:

[image: branch-develop]

However, if I compare `develop` with `master`  I see 8 files have changed:

[image: comparing develop with master]

What could be the reason for this difference shown in message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have master and develop branch. develop branch shows it's 20 commits ahead and 1429 commits behind master (ref Image 1) However if I compare the develop with master branch I see 8 files has changed (Ref Image 2).

The `develop` branch started from `master` some time ago.
During this time, 1429 commits have been added in `master`,
and 20 commits have been added to `develop`.
In these 20 commits, a total of 8 files were modified.

Comment: Thanks. How to fix it ?

Comment: For more info - If you look at develop branch in image - it has 3453 commits and master has 4862 commits. Difference of these two is 1409 and 20 commits have been made lately in develop branch.

Comment: How to "fix" it depends on what you want to achieve. I can take a guess. Most probably you want to rebase `develop` on top of `master`, so that if `master` as `X` number of commits, `develop` would have `X + 20` commits. You can do that with `git rebase origin/master`.